# While with variable

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to make a while with only variable from function.

This is my listing pages code and it works.

```
$pages_table = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages');
$pages_table->execute();

while($pages_list = $pages_table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $pages_list['name'];
}
```

But i want to this one and it is not working.

```
function page_list() {
    global $connect;
    $pages_table = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages');
    $pages_table->execute();
    return $pages_list = $pages_table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
while (page_list()) {
    echo $pages_list['name'];
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: By "it is not working" what do you mean exactly? plus, why are you assigning the value to a variable before returning it in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because each time you call `page_list()`, you are executing a new query.

You could:

1. Return the statement:

   ```
   function page_list() {
       global $connect;
       $pages_table = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages');
       $pages_table->execute();
       return $pages_table ;
   }

   $pages_table = page_list();
   while ($pages_list = $pages_table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $pages_list['name'];
   }
   ```
2. Or use [`fetchAll()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and `foreach()`:

   ```
   function page_list() {
       global $connect;
       $pages_table = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages');
       $pages_table->execute();
       return $pages_table->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
   }

   foreach (page_list() as $pages_list) {
       echo $pages_list['name'];
   }
   ```
3. Or using [generators](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php) with [`yield`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield) (since PHP 5.5):

   ```
   function page_list() {
       global $connect;
       $pages_table = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages');
       $pages_table->execute();
       while($row = $pages_table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { yield $row; }
   }

   foreach (page_list() as $pages_list) {
       echo $pages_list['name'];
   }
   ```